# What is the difference between ffmpeg -thread and ffmpeg-mt?

Tags: multithreading, ffmpeg

Post `ffmpeg-mt`'s merge with `ffmpeg`...

> *March 21, 2011*
>
> *Today FFmpeg-mt, the multithreaded decoding branch, has been merged into FFmpeg. This has been a long awaited merge, and we would like to thank Alexander Strange for his patience and hard work.*

... what is to be expected of `ffmpeg -thread` usage? Is this an under-the-hood transition or are `ffmpeg` users supposed to move their code to `ffmpeg-mt` to leverage multi-cores?

Answer (score 0):

> I believe ffmpeg-mt has multithreaded decoders as well as a
>   multithreaded encoders.
>
> Since conversions involve both decoding and
>   encoding, the -mt version should be faster.

PS: This is an old question, but since is the first google result, I just added the answer from the videohelp forums https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/317689-Difference-between-ffmpeg-threads-and-ffmpeg-mt